# The validation loss and training loss are low and close to each other but there exists high test loss?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm, data-leakage

I have been using CNN-LSTM for action recognition with dataset split 70% for training , 20% for validation , 10% for testing and after training , the validation loss and training loss were very close to each other and they were low but the model performed poorly on the test set . I believe it might be because of Data leakage that my test set wasn't representative enough for the training set and validation set . But is this truly the problem or are there other cases?